# How to get information of microsoft account?

Tags: c#, rest, email, uwp, outlook

I have app that can send and receive messages from outlook via mailkit. But I have to take information like this [account info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j58Ib.png)

Is there any api that can provide access to this information? In addition I have exact email adress. May it can help.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/msgraph-access-user-data/

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access it through Exchange Web Services (The EWS Managed API provides an object-based interface for retrieving user settings.).

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Autodiscover;

public static GetUserSettingsResponse GetUserSettings(
    AutodiscoverService service,
    string emailAddress,
    int maxHops,
    params UserSettingName[] settings)
{
    Uri url = null;
    GetUserSettingsResponse response = null;
    for (int attempt = 0; attempt < maxHops; attempt++)
    {
        service.Url = url;
        service.EnableScpLookup = (attempt < 2);
        response = service.GetUserSettings(emailAddress, settings);
        if (response.ErrorCode == AutodiscoverErrorCode.RedirectAddress)
        {
            url = new Uri(response.RedirectTarget);
        }
        else if (response.ErrorCode == AutodiscoverErrorCode.RedirectUrl)
        {
            url = new Uri(response.RedirectTarget);
        }
        else
        {
            return response;
        }
    }
    
}
```